# UITextView in Cell Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitextview

I have been messing with these constraints for hours and cannot figure this out.
I need to have Dynamic cell height with my text view.

[image]
[image]

As you can see its overlapping my time stamp. As of right now I have zero(no) constraints on the time stamp. I have tried every combination possible to make this work and I cant get it.

Also am using

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        //TableView Cell word wrap (Dynamic Text)
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 78
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: try giving bottom constraint to your message label .(leading,trailing,top,bottom)

Comment: This is a textView not a label. And I tried that.

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31236546/automatically-change-cell-height-based-on-content-swift/42111511#42111511

Comment: set bottom constraint with timestamp label and disable scroll of textview .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**For Swift 3.1, 4.0**

It will be achieved by setting constraints and `UITableViewAutomaticDimensions`.

**Step 1:**

[image]

**Step 2:**

[image]

**Step 3:**

[image]

**Step 4:**

Remove Scrolling for `UITextView`

[image]

**Step 5:**

Add Below code,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

**Note:**

If you have `UILabel` then, Replace `UITextView` to `UILabel` from above solution and `label.numberOfLines = 0`.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: you are an amazing help And I coudnt be more greatfull.

Comment: Awesome solution! I needed it.

Comment: @mumu , Thanks mate :D

Answer (score 1):

If your cell height is dependent on text size then follow this: Add the method in your ViewController.swift

```
    func calculateHeight(inString:String) -> CGFloat {
         let messageString = inString
         let attributes : [String : Any] = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)]

     let attributedString : NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: messageString, attributes: attributes)

     let rect : CGRect = attributedString.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: 222.0, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)

      let requredSize:CGRect = rect
      return requredSize.height
}
```

Set the width of your text label Then call this function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            heightOfRow = self.calculateHeight(inString: conversations[indexPath.row].description)

            return (heightOfRow + 60.0)
    }
```

For Basic cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
           return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

**This function will not work for custom cells.**

If your cell height is dependent on image height, then return image height + someFloatValueAccordingToYourChoice.

Hope it will work.

Comment: what is that `width: 222.0` in `func calculateHeight(inString:String)`?

Comment: `func calculateHeight(inString:String)` is superb :D

Comment: I used it as cell width. Glad it helped :)

Comment: :p You are the boss. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

User vertical spacing between the timeStamp and the message, and set the constant to >=2

Comment: then what constraints should i put on the timeStamp?

Comment: I would set it to the default it shows you for height and bottom spacing. @codechicksrock

Comment: it seems to be working with the vertical constraint but now i cant figure out the timeStamp constraint for it to work.

Comment: Set width, height, bottom and left spacing for the timestamp. set the width to something you know the timestamp will not surpass. then align the timestamp text Left Aligned. I would do bottom spacing 2 and left spacing 6 @codechicksrock

Comment: I still cant seem to get it right. The vertical pacing seems to work but doesnt make it dynamically size the cell because I cant get the timeStamp right

Comment: Its not working any other sudgestions for the timeStamp label