# Custom UITableViewCell not filling up the size of UITableView (SWIFT 3)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I made a custom UITableViewCell with the following properties:

```
    cityNameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: self.frame.width/2, height: self.frame.height))     
    degreeLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: self.frame.width - 50, y: 0, width: 50, height: self.frame.height))
    degreeLabel.textAlignment = .left
    degreeLabel.text = "12C"

    contentView.layer.addSublayer(setupGradient())
    contentView.addSubview(cityNameLabel)
    contentView.addSubview(degreeLabel)
```

And I dequeued the cell, registered it, and set the frame in my UIViewController's tableviewcontroller like this:

```
        tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 60, width: view.frame.width, height: 200))
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.3, green: 0.3, blue: 0.3, alpha: 0.3)
        tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 3
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.rowHeight = 60
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.register(SettingsCityTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuse)
```

And then set it up as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuse, for: indexPath) as? SettingsCityTableViewCell {
            cell.cityNameLabel.text = cityList.list[indexPath.row].name
            return cell
        }
        else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }
```

However, the UITableViewCell does not fill the entirety of the UITableView's frame. Like this:

[image]

(The cell doesn't fit the tableview... )

EDIT:
I would also like to solve this issue programmatically, as I don't really use storyboards for coding on Swift. Thank you!

Comment: see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43485729/uitextview-in-cell-swift/43535950#43535950

Comment: Try to update frames of cell's subviews inside your custom cell inside awakeFromNib() or  didLayoutSubviews() method. Don't allocate outlets there, just make their frames update

Comment: @RAJAMOHAN-S I saw the article, but I do all my coding programmatically, and I wanted to the programmatic way of doing it--will edit my question to be clearer! Thanks!

Comment: @chemo have you tried to update frames as I mentioned?

Comment: @woof I just tried in different ways, but things got even weirder. In the picture above, you'll notice that the cell has a CAGradientLayer(I left that part out in the code above). Now, when I updated the frames for the CAGradientLayer and the two UILabels in override layoutSubviews(), the CAGradientLayer now fills the entirety of the cell, but the UILabels remain the same. And now, the layer is covering up the UILabels in the view hierarchy no matter what I try. Any help please?

Comment: @Woof So yes, your solution worked for my CAGradientLayer, but not for my UILabels. And the new problem of the layer covering up my UILabels. (I just tried creating a new UIView and adding the layer to that new UIView, and inserting this UIView BELOW the two UILabels, but for some reason, the UIView seems to come out on top, covering up the two UILabels.)

Comment: Make sure that your layoutSubviews() doesn't contain addSubview(), as I said you should set only frame like cityNameLabel.frame = frame. This method is calling several times in the cell, so if you're adding some subviews there, they will always cover your outlets

Comment: If you want to implement UI in code, instead of using frame, why don't you use autolayout with a third party such as SnapKit? I think autolayout is better than calculate frame manually.

Comment: add this code viewdidappear.       tableView.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width

Comment: Have you tried **heightForRow_atIndexPath** delegate method to give proper height to your row. And also make sure you have not written any ambiguous code in your **setupGradient()** method.